# How to put date(parsed from csv) in Python to mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I've made separate simple example just to check what method would work with date in my case and didn't find any solution.

we have:

1. db table:

```
CREATE TABLE `main_test` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DATESTAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_1` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_3` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_4` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_5` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

2. code

```
import csv
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(
    user="test_user",
    password="u4534@F_18bbb",
    host="localhost",
    database="example_sch",
    port=3306,
    )

with open("example_v2.csv", "r", encoding="cp1251") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")

    for line in reader:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `main_test` (`DATESTAMP`,`col_1`,`col_2`,`col_3`,`col_4`,`col_5`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        cursor.execute(sql_insert,(line["DATESTAMP"],line["csv_col1"], line["csv_col2"], line["csv_col3"], line["csv_col4"], line["csv_col5"]))
        print(line)


    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

3. CSV file example_v2.csv:

```
DATESTAMP,csv_col1,csv_col2,csv_col3,csv_col4,csv_col5,
"22.04.2022 0:00:00","15347","random_symb_1","1abc","1def","1AAAAAAAAAA",
"23.04.2022 0:00:00","25347","random_symb_2","2abc","2def","2AAAAAAAAAA",
"24.04.2022 0:00:00","3234","random_symb_3","3abc","3def","3AAAAAAAAAA",
"25.04.2022 0:00:00","45677","random_symb_4","4abc","4def","4AAAAAAAAAA",
"26.04.2022 0:00:00","55675","random_symb_5","5abc","5def","5AAAAAAAAAA",
```

4. Trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Project_1/example_db_work_v2.py", line 18, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql_insert,(line["DATESTAMP"],line["csv_col1"], line["csv_col2"], line["csv_col3"], line["csv_col4"], line["csv_col5"]))
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '22.04.2022 0:00:00' for column 'DATESTAMP' at row 1")
```

Could you please assist in even find the documentation fit my case or indicate the direction.
I've already tried a lot of methods such as:

```
str(d.strfdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

etc.

Comment: why do you have just 5 placeholders in `VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)` when you want to pass/insert 6 values? The error is clear *not all arguments converted during string formatting*

Comment: Same result meaning that you get exactly the same error? I doubt it... Do you get different error? I would guess there is problem with the datetime format, but not the number of arguments. Edit your question to include the exact traceback you get with the correct number of placerholders.

Comment: @buran corrected, updated code and trace in a question, sorry, can't edit comment, due 5 min freeze

Comment: your datestamp format should look like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @buran and @Dean-Van-Greunen

let me show you my version of answer as a first but not last step, thats not elegant at all, but it works.

```
        date = line["DATESTAMP"][6:-8] + "-" + line["DATESTAMP"][3:-13] + "-" + line["DATESTAMP"][:-16]
        time = line["DATESTAMP"][11:6] + "-" + line["DATESTAMP"][13:-3] + "-" + line["DATESTAMP"][16:]
        date_time = date + time
```

let me show also more elegant version, thanks to @baron for focusing my attention on the format issue in comments

```
def date_convert(date_to_convert):
    return datetime.strptime(date_to_convert, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

than use it this way:

```
date_time = date_convert(line["DATESTAMP"])

cursor.execute(sql_insert,(date_time, line["csv_col1"], line["csv_col2"], line["csv_col3"], line["csv_col4"], line["csv_col5"]))
```

Comment: IMHO, using a function would make sense if you pass form and to format strings. As it is now, it's better just to use the return line directly

Comment: @buran please show me what exactly you mean?

Comment: it's in my code... but `date_time = datetime.strptime(date_to_convert, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`. That is instead of defining a function and using it

Comment: And if you want more versatile function `def date_convert(str_to_convert, from_fmt='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S', to_fmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):` then use `from_fmt` and `to_fmt`. This way you can pass whatever format strings you want, not use hard-coded format strings\

Comment: Thank you, I just thought if I understood you wrong, now I see thank you. you are right, the constants will work better, for sure, here I didn't use it just to make an example clear...  btw, I also realised that it's important to check if line datetime element is not empty, to prevent errors in str conversions. Again **thank you so much for spending your time**, I thought I tried all,, but my main mistake was **income format** I didn't write it correctly as for real didn't even recognise it's wrong.

Comment: currently looking at my code, this code isn't fine at all

Comment: totally not fine

Answer (score 0):

try something within these lines:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

# skip some code for brevity
cursor = conn.cursor()
with open("example_v2.csv", "r", encoding="cp1251") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")

    for line in reader:
        line[0] = datetime.strptime(line[0], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `main_test` (`DATESTAMP`,`col_1`,`col_2`,`col_3`,`col_4`,`col_5`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        cursor.execute(sql_insert, line)
```

Note, the code could use `exectemany`, or read/pass dict if header in the csv file is same as field names in the database table, etc.

Comment: let me ask you, you used only "line" in this `cursor.execute(sql_insert, line)` please let me know how other columns will be passed to the execute if you pass only the date?

Comment: `line` is a list, contain all the values. Using csvDictReader, unless you pass dict to `cursor.execute` and names in the placeholdes (but then the keys of the dict should match) just clutters the code, because you access each value by key.

Comment: I also tried myself close to yours version please see code below `def date_convert(date_to_convert):
    return datetime.strptime(date_to_convert, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`
    I used it this way  `date_time = date_convert(line["DATESTAMP"])   `  and it hadn't worked, the trace was: `File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '22.04.2022 0:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

Comment: code in comments in impossible to read. But, note that your format string is wrong, look at my format strings for datetime

Comment: oh I just understood, thank you for your comment, you just put it in the line before all previous keys, instead previous one by this `line[0] `

Comment: you are correct, that was my mistake in first condition I should write the current format, in the last one the format I want to get as a result